# Allergic online resources for traveling

Tags: online-resources, health

I and many millions more are allergic to one thing or another. I am now wondering if there are any online resources, in English (but preferably more languages), that provide global or regional allergy information.

What I want to know is for example "Is there a pet and smoke-free hotel in Beijing?" "What restaurants in Chicago provide ingredient declaration/allergy friendly menus?" "Is there a detergent available in x region without x substance?" "Where are there hotels without feathers in the covers and pillows in Paris?"

Many of these questions can be answered for Sweden with the use of [Astma och Allergiförbundets](http://www.astmaoallergiforbundet.se/) website or by contacting them. The website is only in Swedish though, however contacting them can probably yield better results for the non-swedish seakers.

If there is a global site or organization providing this or part of this information this question can be answered. However if there are only regional sites this question will result in lists. So I would like to make it a community wiki.

Answer (score 2):

For New Zealand, much information is provided through a charity called [Allergy New Zealand](http://www.allergy.org.nz/) and provides reliable information, education and support.  The idea being for children with allergies, but the information on food recalls and the like is totally relevant to the rest of us as well.

There's a government site as well, from the Ministry for Primary Industries on [Allergies and intolerances](http://www.foodsmart.govt.nz/allergies-intolerances/).